# Why kubectl give unable to list cronjob error while trying to list pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm having a weird issue at times. When trying to list pods in a Kubernetes cluster, it gives me the same exact error, which has nothing to do with cronjobs. This issue get fixed if I restart the terminal (sometimes I have to restart the computer). When I'm having this issue, I checked with other computers, they don't have any issues. I believe something wrong on my  end. Does anyone have any idea why I end up having this issue?

```
➜  ~ kubectl get pods
Error from server (NotFound): Unable to list "tap.linkerd.io/v1alpha1, Resource=cronjobs": the server could not find the requested resource (get cronjobs.tap.linkerd.io)
```

Edit:

I can list deployments, cronjobs without any issues. This is happening only when I do get pods. Also it gets fixed by itself if I wait some time.

Comment: you are getting this error from linkerd service mesh but not directly from kubernetes, check whether you have specified all the required annotations correctly. follow this [doc](https://linkerd.io/2.12/tasks/troubleshooting/) for validating and troubleshooting linkerd.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an indication of version mismatch between your kubectl client and your server, not anything specific to Linkerd. You can confirm with `kubectl version --short` whether or not that is the case.

Comment: No it's not the case. I just had this issue again and checked the version. `Client Version: v1.23.17
Server Version: v1.23.16-eks-48e63af`